# how controlling the turtle in screen can help in controlling the robot in the real wold

Tags: ros, robot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

how controlling the turtle in screen can help in controlling the robot in the real wold

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/53586/how-controlling-the-turtle-in-screen-can-help-in-controlling-the-robot-in-the-real-wold/) by [viki](https://answers.ros.org/users/3971/viki/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2013-01-28

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Erwan R.](https://answers.ros.org/users/2176/erwan-r./) on 2013-01-28**:
I don't understand your question. Please provide more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When you control turtle on your screen, ur publishing movement commands on a topic to which turtle is subscribed. In a similar way you can control a real bot by publishing velocity command on a topic to which bot is subscribed. You can use the same code just by changing the topic name provided datatype of topic is same. In most cases topic is of type "geometry_msgs::Twist".

---

Originally posted by [ayush_dewan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2268/ayush_dewan/) with karma: 1610 on 2013-01-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [viki](https://answers.ros.org/users/3971/viki/) on 2013-01-28**:
ok. thank you for reply

**Comment by [viki](https://answers.ros.org/users/3971/viki/) on 2013-01-28**:
ok. thank you for reply